# livy - server limit number of jobs

Tags: apache-spark, livy

I am looking for some configuration in order to limit my livy server to **not use more than X cores or number of jobs**, I saw that someone already asked this in the Jira issues (https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/LIVY-74 ), and he got answered that Yarn is doing that, but I don't need yarn since I don't want to control my jobs / sessions per user and I don't have any other resources to manage except spark.

Answer (score 0):

You can take these properties as an example:

```
livy.spark.driver.cores 1
livy.spark.driver.memory    512m
livy.spark.dynamicAllocation.cachedExecutorIdleTimeout  
livy.spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled    true
livy.spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors   1
livy.spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors   5
livy.spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors   1
livy.spark.executor.cores   2
livy.spark.executor.instances   5
livy.spark.executor.memory  2G
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Livy 0.5, there's now a config setting to limit the number of jobs running in parallel. The setting is called `livy.server.session.max-creation`:

```
// Max creating session in livyServer
val SESSION_MAX_CREATION = Entry("livy.server.session.max-creation", 100)
```

This is [the PR that introduced it](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/pull/58/files).