# Concurrency problems in Spark application

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am junior developer that happen to responsible for spark application and I am desperately finding the solution to this application.

My spark application has intermediate server that receive user request and submit spark job to the cluster using **client** mode which create spark session on the server.

And this server is the bottleneck! If there are many concurrent, there will be many spark session on the same server and this server will be out of resource in just 10 concurrents (my goal is to have 100-200 concurrents).

My questions are

1. Can submitting the spark job in **cluster** mode help eliminate this bottleneck?
2. Does anyone happen to implement the Spark Application with the requirements similar or more extreme than this application? How can one solve the concurrency problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look at [Apache Livy](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/)

Comment: Yes, in fact the intermediate server is Livy. However, infra team have set the submit mode of the Livy as client mode. I suggest to switch to cluster mode but I am not 100% sure that it can solve the problem.

Comment: If you already are using Livy, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44094852/2129801). If you are using Yarn as cluster manager, [Yarn queues](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html) might also be an option. PS: Git rid of the infra team and switch to DevOps ;-)

Comment: Thanks! The application implement both Livy and Yarn. However, if there are too many queue waiting in the YARN, there will be outofmemory error: unable to create new native thread. I am suspicious that the Spark Session was created in the Livy server (since it is config as Client mode) and I guess that by changing to cluster mode will help (but not 100% sure though).